# I have multiple TcpClient connections, how do I select a specific one?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have a **TCP Client**

```cs
            Log.Warn("Trying to connect to " + IP);
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(IP, Port);
            string command = "";
            while (!command.Contains("quit"))
            {
                Log.WriteSingle("localhost@", ConsoleColor.DarkYellow);
                Log.WriteSingle(IP + ":", ConsoleColor.Yellow);
                command = Console.ReadLine();

                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);

                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                Log.Success("Sent command to network.");
                // Buffer to store the response bytes.
                data = new Byte[256];
                // String to store the response ASCII representation.
                String responseData = String.Empty;

                // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
                Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                Log.Write("Server Says: " + responseData, ConsoleColor.DarkYellow);
            }
```

and a **TCP Server**

```cs
 while(true)
            {
                Log.Write("Waiting for connection...");
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                Log.Success("Connected! ");
 
                //Update list (Currently useless)
                clientList.Add(client);
 
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(()=>ConnectClient(client,bytes,data))); 
                t.Start();
            }
 
        public static void ConnectClient(TcpClient _client, byte[] _bytes, string _data)
        {
             _data = null;
        
                NetworkStream stream = _client.GetStream();
                int i;
                while((i = stream.Read(_bytes,0,_bytes.Length))!=0)
                {
                    _data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_bytes,0,i);
                    Log.Write("Recieved: "+_data, ConsoleColor.Cyan);
 
                    //Send back to client
                    _data = _data.ToUpper();
 
                    byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_data);
                    stream.Write(msg,0,msg.Length);
                    Log.Write("Sent: "+_data);
                }
 
                _client.Close();
        }
```

I have it setup so the server listens to client connections and pop them off in a new thread once they connect. The client can send the server a string, and the server reflects it back.

I assume I can use a dictionary to assign an ID and store the client, or even just a simple List.

How would I structure it so I can add them to a List or a Dictionary and still be able to connect multiple clients?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put your `accept()` loop in a thread of its own.  It can add to the list each time a new client connects.

Leave your main thread to manage all the client threads, including the `accept()` thread.